# Create new object with relation in Parse with React Native

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs, react-native

There seems to be no documentation on how to create a new Parse Object with a Relation with [Parse-ReactNative](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact) using `ParseReact.Mutation.Create`. I resorted to this:

```
function createRow(relatedObject, data) {
  ParseReact.Mutation.Create('objectClass', data)
    .dispatch()
    .then(function(newRow) {
      ParseReact.Mutation.AddRelation(newRow, 'relationColumn', relatedObject)
    });
}
```

Which is creating the new `objectClass` Parse Object, but the column `relationColumn` doesn't display the relation with the given `relatedObject`.

Any idea on how this can be done, preferably in one query with the `ParseReact.Mutation.Create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so my code is working with `ParseReact.Mutation.AddRelation`, here it is:

```
ParseReact.Mutation.AddRelation({
                          "className": newRow.className,
                          "objectId": newRow.id.objectId}, 'groceryRequestRelation',[{
                          "__type":"Pointer",
                          "className":"ClassThePointerPointingTo",
                          "objectId":"ObjectIdOfClassThePointerIsPointingTo"
                        }]).dispatch()
```

@naoisegolden you didn't put `.dispatch()` at the end of the `AddRelation` so that might be an issue.

Another thing that took me forever to figure out was I was using the ***wrong*** `objectId` within my `AddRelation`, I ***should be*** using the `objectId` of the class that ***the pointer is pointing to***, but I was using the `objectId` of the class that the `relation` belongs to...

If this still doesn't work for you, try the REST way to do this:

```
var data = {
      "groceryRequestRelation":{"__op":"AddRelation",
      "objects":
      [{
        "__type":"Pointer",
        "className":"ClassThePointerIsPointingTo",
        "objectId":"ObjectIdOfClassThePointerIsPointingTo"
      }
      ]
    }
  };

        var url = "https://api.parse.com";
        url += "/1/classes/Classname/objectId";
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP_ID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_REST_KEY,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("inside add relation rest")
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseText) => {
          console.log(responseText);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        })
        .done();
```

Comment: Adding dispatch() for AddRelation did the trick for me. Thanks Kevin!

Comment: You can also pass an array of objects as the last parameter in AddRelation. For ex. you can pass an array of User objects if you want to add that relation to a class.

Comment: @muttapp np, glad to help!